# Copy contents of one directory to another

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby, how can I copy the *contents* of one directory to another? For example, given (non-empty) directories A and B:

```
A/
  bar
  foo
B/
  jam
  jim
```

I want to copy everything from A into B, resulting in:

```
A/
  bar
  foo
B/
  bar
  foo
  jam
  jim
```

I cannot use [`FileUtils.cp_r`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r) because it copies the directory itself:

```ruby
irb(main):001:0> require 'fileutils'
#=> true
irb(main):002:0> Dir['**/*']
#=> ["A", "A/bar", "A/foo", "B", "B/jam", "B/jim"]
irb(main):003:0> FileUtils.cp_r('A','B')
#=> nil
irb(main):004:0> Dir['**/*']
#=> ["A", "A/bar", "A/foo", "B", "B/A", "B/A/bar", "B/A/foo", "B/jam", "B/jim"]
```

Is there a better (shorter, more efficient) answer than the following?

```
Dir['A/*'].each{ |f| FileUtils.cp(f,"B") }
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Using FileUtil's `cp_r` method, simply add `/.` at end of the source directory parameter.

Example from Ruby doc below. Assumes a current working directory with src & dest directories.

```
 FileUtils.cp_r 'src/.', 'dest'
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r

Comment: While the answers by CasualCoder and bta are excellent for when you have a list of files to copy to a common destination, this is truly the best answer. (Least typing, least method calls.) Good job for reading the documentation fully.

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(Dir['A/*'],'B')
```

Comment: Though in this case, the target directory is not automatically created.

Answer (score 17):

When using `FileUtils.cp_r`, be aware that the first argument can also be a list of files.  Try something like:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(Dir.glob('A/*'), 'B')
```